# Chatterbot: Is it possible to create different database.db to different bot?

Tags: python, chatterbot

I'm using chatterbot to build an NPCbot.

I want to create the bot with different dialogs due to different situations.
So I use different bots to deal with it.

However, the data will store into one file(database.db) so all the dialog still blend together.
Is there a way to create different databases for different bot? I prefer the default one which the file name is "database.db."

In the attach image, the file I circled is the database I refer. I hope I can create different ones which corresponding to different bots.

The screenshot also shows that I have different bots.(normalJack, angryJack and betJack).

The training way I choose is list training btw.

[image: database file I refer]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out now. I know using SQL will create different database files.
but I was using the old version chatterbot which led to that when I used SQLstorage, it didn't work properly. So I gave up using it.
After upgrade chatterbot, it worked.